# Facebook-style multiple image upload

Tags: php, jquery, image, facebook, file-upload

I am searching for multiple image upload just like facebook  and found the below answers on internet . ( I see even this feature with some forums software too)

1) Use HTML 5 :- Only the latest browsers are supporting this . I think still IE 9 is not supporting it ( Facebook one works good with all browsers )

2) http://www.uploadify.com/ :- But this one using flash technologies

3) http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-file-element/ :- This one works great , But can not select multiple files in one shot . We have to select one by one using one browse button

4) http://code.google.com/p/noswfupload/ :- This one was there from 2009 and I don't see many people using it ( Not sure what the problem with this one )

But none of them look good like Facebook Or forums ones . Could any body help me to find the best one similar to Facebook?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Kiran

Comment: nothing free looks good. hence its a tutorial for you to build on or toooo cruddy to get money for

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence Cherone for the information . any good tutorials for it that helps to implement it ? Or any rough idea how much it costs to get it done ..? Thanks again

Comment: [This post](http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload) looks helpful for what you're trying to do.

Comment: btw the facebook one uses flash like Uploadify, right click the `Select Photos` button

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence Cherone for the information . Sorry I didn't notice that facebook is using flash . Thanks for that

Comment: @ Jimmy Sawczuk :- Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2) http://www.uploadify.com/ :- But this one using flash technologies

So is Facebook.

> But none of them look good like Facebook Or forums ones .

So customize them. SWFUpload and Uploadify are easily styled to look however you want.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with Uploadify? It works great!

Comment: Thanks Michiel Pater for the infromation

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select multiple files in one shot you must:

1. Use a Flash solution.
2. Use HTML + D&D.

If you check Facebook photo uploader, it is made with flash.

Comment: D&D = Dungeons and Dragons :)